# Suggest me the uri to create workorder using objectstructure REST service in maximo 7.5

Tags: rest, service, uri, maximo

I am able to query workorder using below uri

```
http://<server:port>/maxrest/rest/os/mxwo?_lid=username&_lpwd=password&siteid=bedford
```

can anyone guide me to modify above uri to create workorders with

```
wonum=somename
siteid=bedford
description=TestPM
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal browsers don't do POST operation, so either use a REST Client or save the following in an HTML file and open in a browser to create a workorder.

```
<form name="input" action="http://<server:port>/maxrest/rest/os/mxwo?_lid=username&_lpwd=password" method="POST">

    Description <input name="DESCRIPTION" value="Description will go here" type="text"> <p/>
    SITEID <input name="SITEID" value="BEDFORD" type="text"> <p/>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```